# C: creating array of strings from delimited source string

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

What would be an efficient way of converting a delimited string into an array of strings in C (not C++)?  For example, I might have:

```
char *input = "valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./a.out"
```

The source string will always have only a single space as the delimiter. And I would like a malloc'ed array of malloc'ed strings `char *myarray[]` such that:

```
myarray[0]=="valgrind"
myarray[1]=="--leak-check=yes"
...
```

**Edit** I have to assume that there are an arbitrary number of tokens in the `inputString` so I can't just limit it to 10 or something.

I've attempted a messy solution with `strtok` and a linked list I've implemented, but valgrind complained so much that I gave up.

(If you're wondering, this is for a basic Unix shell I'm trying to write.)

Comment: @Sneesh: This is an excellent example of how you can do it in C as the old adage is 'There are many ways to skin a cat...' +1 from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's about something like:

```
char* string = "valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./a.out";
char** args = (char**)malloc(MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*));
memset(args, 0, sizeof(char*)*MAX_ARGS);

char* curToken = strtok(string, " \t");

for (int i = 0; curToken != NULL; ++i)
{
  args[i] = strdup(curToken);
  curToken = strtok(NULL, " \t");
}
```

Comment: Actually I think that using a 256 buffer of pointers to strings wouldn't be such a waste, unless you really need to preserve memory..

Comment: strtok() modifies the input string, so using it on a string literal will crash on some platforms.

Comment: I could assume that `MAX_ARGS` is something safe like 10,000, but the code still ought to work for 10,001 args...

Comment: that's true, actually strtok() usually replaces the first delimiter at the end of a token with \0 to easily return the token. It was just to explain the snippet :)

Comment: The application of this is eventually going to be using the array as a parameter to `execv`, so it's the array of arguments to whatever command I'm calling.

Comment: Yes, but using a list will waste double the space.. so do you really need to handle 10000+ params? Is it a constraint of the project or what?

Comment: Ok, so the only difference is using a linked list.. what's your problem with it? you just strdup() in a list element

Comment: Yes, it's a constraint of the project: "Do not assume that there is a limit on the number of args to a given command."

The input in general is limited to 4096 bytes, so I suppose 4096 would work for `MAX_ARGS` now that I think of it, no?

Comment: ofc, unless you can use half-bytes :D btw if you need help with the list I can edit the snippet..

Comment: It'd be easy to make MAX_ARGS not be a constant and determine it at runtime.  Either just iterate over the input and count spaces, or call `strlen()` and assume a worst case scenario where every character is a space.

Answer (score 2):

if you have all of the input in `input` to begin with then you can never have more tokens than `strlen(input)`. If you don't allow "" as a token, then you can never have more than `strlen(input)/2` tokens. So unless `input` is *huge* you can safely write.

```
char ** myarray = malloc( (strlen(input)/2) * sizeof(char*) );

int NumActualTokens = 0;
while (char * pToken = get_token_copy(input))
{ 
   myarray[++NumActualTokens] = pToken;
   input = skip_token(input);
}

char ** myarray = (char**) realloc(myarray, NumActualTokens * sizeof(char*));
```

As a further optimization, you can keep `input` around and just replace spaces with \0 and put pointers into the `input` buffer into myarray[].  No need for a separate malloc for each token unless for some reason you *need* to free them individually.

Comment: Using your `strlen(input)/2` idea- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Were you remembering to malloc an extra byte for the terminating null that marks the end of string?

Comment: Yes: `char *singleToken = (char *)malloc(strlen(tokPtr)*sizeof(char)+1);` where `tokPtr` was the return value of `strtok`.

Answer (score 1):

From the `strsep(3)` manpage on OSX:

```
   char **ap, *argv[10], *inputstring;

   for (ap = argv; (*ap = strsep(&inputstring, " \t")) != NULL;)
           if (**ap != '\0')
                   if (++ap >= &argv[10])
                           break;
```

Edited for arbitrary # of tokens:

```
char **ap, **argv, *inputstring;

int arglen = 10;
argv = calloc(arglen, sizeof(char*));
for (ap = argv; (*ap = strsep(&inputstring, " \t")) != NULL;)
    if (**ap != '\0')
        if (++ap >= &argv[arglen])
        {
            arglen += 10;
            argv = realloc(argv, arglen);
            ap = &argv[arglen-10];
        }
```

Or something close to that.  The above may not work, but if not it's not far off.  Building a linked list would be more efficient than continually calling `realloc`, but that's really besides the point - the point is how best to make use of `strsep`.

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to mention that I have to assume that there's an arbitrary number of tokens in the `inputString`- I can't assume 10, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the other answers, for a beginner in C, it would look complex due to the tight size of code, I thought I would put this in for a beginner, it might be easier to actually parse the string instead of using `strtok`...something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char **parseInput(const char *str, int *nLen);
void resizeptr(char ***, int nLen);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int maxLen = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char **ptr = NULL;
    char *str = "valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./a.out";
    ptr = parseInput(str, &maxLen);
    if (!ptr) printf("Error!\n");
    else{
        for (i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}

char **parseInput(const char *str, int *Index){
    char **pStr = NULL;
    char *ptr = (char *)str;
    int charPos = 0, indx = 0;
    while (ptr++ && *ptr){
        if (!isspace(*ptr) && *ptr) charPos++;
        else{
            resizeptr(&ptr, ++indx);
            pStr[indx-1] = (char *)malloc(((charPos+1) * sizeof(char))+1);
            if (!pStr[indx-1]) return NULL;
            strncpy(pStr[indx-1], ptr - (charPos+1), charPos+1);
            pStr[indx-1][charPos+1]='\0';
            charPos = 0;
        }
    }
    if (charPos > 0){
        resizeptr(&pStr, ++indx);
        pStr[indx-1] = (char *)malloc(((charPos+1) * sizeof(char))+1);
        if (!pStr[indx-1]) return NULL;
        strncpy(pStr[indx-1], ptr - (charPos+1), charPos+1);
        pStr[indx-1][charPos+1]='\0';
    }
    *Index = indx;
    return (char **)pStr;
}

void resizeptr(char ***ptr, int nLen){
    if (*(ptr) == (char **)NULL){
        *(ptr) = (char **)malloc(nLen * sizeof(char*));
        if (!*(ptr)) perror("error!");
    }else{
        char **tmp = (char **)realloc(*(ptr),nLen);
        if (!tmp) perror("error!");
        *(ptr) = tmp;
    }
}
```

I slightly modified the code to make it easier. The only string function that I used was `strncpy`..sure it is a bit long-winded but it does reallocate the array of strings dynamically instead of using a hard-coded MAX_ARGS, which means that the double pointer is already hogging up memory when only 3 or 4 would do, also which would make the memory usage efficient and tiny, by using `realloc`, the simple parsing is covered by employing `isspace`, as it iterates using the pointer. When a space is encountered, it `realloc`ates the double pointer, and `malloc` the offset to hold the string.

Notice how the triple pointers are used in the `resizeptr` function.. in fact, I thought this would serve an excellent example of a simple C program, pointers, realloc, malloc, passing-by-reference, basic element of parsing a string...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.