# How to change saved address after reallocation

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, realloc

```
struct AD_SINT32Type* = NULL;
foo = (struct mystructArray*)malloc(sizeof(struct mystructArray));
foo[0].x = 45;
foo[0].y = 90;
coords[0] = &foo[0];


foo = (struct mystructArray*)realloc(foo, 2 * sizeof(struct mystructArray));
foo[1].x = 30;
foo[1].y = 15;
coords[1] = &foo[1];
```

After this code `"coords[1]"` points as intended, but `"coords[0]"` points to an the old address before the reallocation.  Is there a way to automatic adapt the address `"coords[0]"` points to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Note that your code is unable to handle errors from `realloc`.

Comment: Store the index instead of the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fully "automatic" way to do this, but in cases like this where reallocation is needed, you often see the use of "offset pointers."  So instead of this:

```
coords[0] = &foo[0];
```

You'd change the type of `coords` to something like `ptrdiff_t[]` and do this:

```
coords[0] = &foo[0] - foo;
```

This way,  you save not the actual pointer, but the offset from the beginning of the allocation.  And that value will never need to change.

Comment: The difference of two pointers yields a `ptrdiff_t`. Any other type might loose information. On 64 bit architectures (P64), an `uint32_t` **will** loose information.

Comment: @Olaf: I have updated my answer to use `ptrdiff_t`.  At least now nobody can complain that I've done something dirty.  On 64-bit you will only lose information storing into a 32-bit int if you have a huge array.  Just so we're clear.

Comment: "something like" still is suspectible imo. `ptrdiff_t` is exactly designed for such. However, as the difference will always be `>= 0` and you actually calculate an index, `size_t` would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to automatic adapt the address "coords[0]" points to?

No.

See [How to update other pointers when realloc moves the memory block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172127/how-to-update-other-pointers-when-realloc-moves-the-memory-block?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to automatic adapt the address "coords[0]" points to?

No. C does not keep track where you store addresses. If you need this, it's your job to keep track.

Another idea is to think outside the box:

- can you restructure your data in a way you don't need to store more than one pointer to the start of the dynamic array?
- can you work with offsets instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just make `coords` a `size_t []` (this is the correct type) and store indexes into `foo` instead of absolute addresses.

Alternatively, after a `realloc` of `foo`, you can update all `coords` entries in a loop.

But the first version migh not be much slower than using addresses, you benchmark before going complicated.