# Need help in reading .txt file which contains a table with blanks?

Tags: c++, text-files, traversal, tabular

Consider this -

"ID_REF"    "GSM887"    "GSM888"    "GSM889"    "GSM890"    "GSM891"
10                 -.427                                       -3.841        .312    0
11                 -.939                         -1             -.024

Now how to recognize blanks when I am traversing through whole text file containing many such entries. I need to find mean of every column so how do I skip blank (null) values. It will be helpful if someone can tell me a way to do it in C++.

Comment: keywords: 'read fixed with columns in c++', you should check your data format whether it is a reliable "fixed with format" (retaining all spaces and line lengths). Then, split your input line at the correct positions and scan these blocks as integers or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the only delemiter is an arbitrary number of spaces, then you can't, because then

```
"ID_REF" "GSM887" "GSM888" "GSM889" "GSM890" "GSM891"
11                 -.939       -1            -.024
```

is the same as

```
"ID_REF" "GSM887" "GSM888" "GSM889" "GSM890" "GSM891"  
11        -.939    -1       -.024
```

check the character codes and hopefully you have /t or whatever a tab character is in there instead of just all spaces.

---

Ah, since you have tabs, your data actually looks like this

```
 "ID_REF"   "GSM887"   "GSM888"   "GSM889"   "GSM890"   "GSM891"  
    11   \t -.939    \t   -1    \t   -.024  \t         \t
```

What you need to do now is called parsing a delimted string to an array.
Something like this [C: creating array of strings from delimited source string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170319/c-creating-array-of-strings-from-delimited-source-string)

or even better, what rubber boots said

Comment: Yeah it has proper tabbing. thanks. Now how does C++ recognizes tabs?

Comment: @Duncan are there any spaces between tabs if no value is given or will you find two (or more) consecutive tabs then?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Matt. You can replace all the spaces with comma in txt (switch it to a csv file in excel) and you will be good to go.